# How to export putty sessions

Tags: putty, session

I'm trying to export putty sessions and import the same in another computer (Desktop to laptop). But as it is suggested here in this [stackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023920/how-to-export-putty-sessions-list#), I have to export "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham". But there is no such registry key exist in my system at all.

I've attached screenshot. As you can see, I've clicked on "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\skype" but there is no SimonTatham key, and I've so many sessions in the "putty configuration" window (right side).
I also searched inside other folders such as "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software", but I couldn't find anywhere.

[image]

Since answers in other threads are so old, I thought newer versions of putty (0.67 is the version I'm using) is storing sessions differently. I'm on Windows 7 and my laptop is Windows 8.1.

Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Look for `SimonTatham` inside the `Wow6432Node` just in case you were running a 32-bit copy of PuTTY. If you still cannot find it, you can [ProcMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) the PuTTY process and check which registry values and files it reads/writes.

Comment: `Wow6432Node` is not really used for `HKCU`, only for `HKLM`. So both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of PuTTY write to the same key (not in `Wow6432Node`).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the official version of PuTTY from the [official source](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), and not one from the many slightly-customized versions that call themselves PuTTY, the registry key you were given is correct.  If you're using the "portable" version of PuTTY, or TuTTY, or many of the others... there is no telling where it might end up.  I believe the portable-versions write the settings to a file instead of a registry as well.

Comment: Oh!!! Until today I thought [putty.org](https://www.putty.org/) was the official website. I'll try installing official version and cross check. Thank you.

Comment: Hello TheCompWiz, even putty.org will redirect to official download page. And there I didn't download .msi installer. I donwloaded 64bit [putty.exe](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w64/putty.exe) under "Alternative binaries". Is it is the portable putty that you have mentioned above?

Comment: No, that isn't the "portable" version.  I was referring to one of the "portableapps.com" versions.  If you click the "About" button in your putty app... what does it say?  Any version I have used that is an unofficial version has a different blob of text in there.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply TheCompWiz, This is the content I get after clicking "About" button.
`PuTTY

Release 0.67

© 1997-2016 Simon Tatham. All rights reserved.`

Comment: are you sure you have any saved sessions?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. Even you can see the last two digits in the screenshot. There are about 16 saved sessions.

Comment: are you sure it is running in your user account?  Perhaps you right-clicked & did a "run-as"?  have you tried searching the entire registry for "SimonTatham" or "PuTTY"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm running in my user account itself. But in my home I tried putty and I'm getting the registry entry but in office its not. In our office we have strict policies and I don't have admin rights. I contacted my IT team guy and took a look into registry but it's not found there. Can you specify any secondary place where putty could have stored sessions?

Comment: Nope.  PuTTY doesn't do "secondary" locations.  No clue what to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled about this problem, too. So I post an answer, even the question is older.

When you open regedit, you have to open it with the credentials of the user the sessions are stored under. Don't use administrator credentials, if the session is not stored for user Administrator.

Comment: You would then need to open the user's SID under `HKEY_Users`